# I want to know whether you understand '...period of the day, in the morning' (?)

Tags: grammar

> I have waited for the **period of the day, in the morning.**

Can the 'period of the day' and 'in the morning' be the apposition?

Comment: Firstly, please select proper tags for your next questions. Secondly, I think "the period" must be a specific time **interval**.

Comment: Can you paraphrase that sentence, to let us know what you are trying to say?

Comment: In every post, please provide a detailed explanation of the **meaning** that you are trying to express along with the example sentence. This will help others understand what you are trying to say and give you the best possible answers.